# Event: ET SCAN Nmap NSE Heartbleed Request

Tags: penetration-test, attack-prevention, vulnerability-scanners, vulnerability, heartbleed

Last night I got this incident on my siem tool:

> Event: ET SCAN Nmap NSE Heartbleed Request.

Incident triggered from blacklisted IP to our open VPN server.

Clicking on the signature content it displayed:

> alert tcp any any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ET SCAN Nmap NSE Heartbleed
>   Request"; flow:established,to_server; content:"|18 03|"; depth:2;
>   byte_test:1,<,4,2; content:"|01|"; offset:5; depth:1;
>   byte_test:2,>,2,3; byte_test:2,>,200,6; content:"|40 00|Nmap
>   ssl-heartbleed"; fast_pattern:2,19; classtype:attempted-recon;
>   sid:2021023; tag:session,5,packets; rev:1;)

Could someone help me on this signature? Is it really nmap scan or the heartbleed issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is both.

NMAP contains a scripting engine that allows custom scripts, such as those that are used to detect vulnerabilities.

In your case, someone used the [ssl-heartbleed](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-heartbleed.html) script to see if an http server was vulnerable on port 443, and it was blocked.

Comment: Thanks dude for the message !!! How come you know it was blocked?

Comment: can you explain msg:"ET SCAN Nmap NSE Heartbleed Request"; flow:established,to_server; content:"|18 03|"; depth:2; byte_test:1,<,4,2; content:"|01|"; offset:5; depth:1; byte_test:2,>,2,3; byte_test:2,>,200,6; content:"|40 00|Nmap ssl-heartbleed"; fast_pattern:2,19; classtype:attempted-recon; sid:2021023; tag:session,5,packets; rev:1;

Comment: @List25 that is the message from your firewall, since it was a blacklisted IP, it blocked the scan, but still showed you what it was trying to do, and since it was NMAP, the scan made its intentions clear

Comment: But in my siem tool, this message coming under signature category!!!!!!!. thats why iam confused whether its firewall or the signature message. If its a firewall can you pinpoint where its showing the blocked stage

Comment: @List25 I inferred that simply from where you listed "Incident triggered from blacklisted IP", generally if an IP is blacklisted, all traffic is blocked